How do "instantiate" and "initialise" differ?
Perhaps due to ignorance on my part, I see them utilized in a manner which appears interchangeable. Definitions online of the terms differ, yet neither definition encompasses any of the technical scenarios in which I've observed both terms utilized, like variable (instantiation/initialisation). Consequently, I'm confused.
Examples:

Initialisation

the preparation of a computer or similar device for operation, in which diagnostic tests are run and the operating system is loaded.


Instantiation


represent as or by an instance.
"a study of two groups who seemed to instantiate productive aspects of this"

Philosophy
(of a universal or abstract concept) be represented by an actual example.





Neither of these appear to encompass the aforementioned situation.

You generally won't find nuances of industry jargon in general purpose dictionaries.

@Barmar, I wasn't aware of that. Do you know why?

because dictionaries are meant for the general public, and it would be difficult for them to keep up with all these nuances.

Can you provide some examples of the actual use of these terms that does not fit the quoted definitions, that you have observed?

@jsw29, maybe. However, it might require some searching. If I remember to, I'll reference an example, if I happen to see one that seems incorrect.

In computer domain, Instantiation = creation of an item/instance/subsystem/object/process. Initialisation = prepare  an existing item to start working.

Initialization and instantiation are fairly closely related concepts in object-oriented computer programming.  As mentioned in the other answer, initialize denotes the assignment of an initial value to a variable.  It can also refer to setting things up generally, to putting things in place at the beginning of some process.  For example, initializing a test routine might require initializing several individual variables, but it might also require calling a function to turn on some piece of machinery.  This concept is not unique to object-oriented programming.  The specific application of the word "initialize" can vary slightly depending on the language, or even depending on the context within a given language.
Instantiation is a somewhat subtler idea, more specific to object-oriented programming.  OOP is built on the concept of "classes," which you can think of as predefined sets of variables that have some relationship to one another.  For example, you might have a class called Book with two variables, Title and Author.
When you want to represent a particular book in your program, you need to have a segment of the computer's memory reserved to hold these two variables with the values pertaining to that book.  For example, you might have one segment of memory set aside to hold the values "George Orwell" and "1984" and another set aside to hold "Aldous Huxley" and "Brave New World."  These are said to be two instances of the Book class.
Accordingly, instantiation is the process of setting up an area of the computer's memory to represent an instance of a class.  Some languages require initialization of these variables as part of the instantiation process.  The end result of the process is generally a reference to that area of memory, in other words, a reference to the object; a reference to the instance of the class in question.
This leads us to the major point of intersection between instantiation and initialization: when you initialize a new variable, you often do so by instantiating an object and initializing its members:
let fahrenheit_451 = create_instance_of <Book> (
    Author = "Ray Bradbury"
    Title = "Fahrenheit 451"
) 


Thank you. That was comprehensive, but concise.

...I searched for the terms individually and attempted to compare, somehow forgetting to specifically query Google for a comparison.
I mention this because an identical query has been answered at Stack Exchange's Stack Overflow, albeit solely in the specific context of Visual Basic .NET (a programming language). However, some of the answers can be reasonably extrapolated to the broader context of this question:

"Initialize" refers creation of an object with initial values of its attributes.
"Instantiate" refers to creation of a hierarhically subordinate object with (at the least, usually) attributes inherited from its superordinate's counterparts.

Consequently, although the terms both describe creation of an entity, the terms differ in what attributes they inherently apply to that created entity.

In VB or otherwise object oriented programming Initialize is to give a value to a variable that has been created; My integer variable is initialized with the value of 2. To Instantiate is to create an instance of class, or variable according to a planned design; to bring into being; The class of Pet has been instantiated as a Dog object.

The concept of instantiation and the concept of subclasses and superclasses -- also known as inheritance -- are both concepts of object-oriented programming, but instantiation does not depend on inheritance.  In other words, a language with no inheritance would still have instantiation.
